# Multiple Many-to-Many relationsship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

The main goal is the ability to have a many to many relationship between the table Mucle and Exercise. I want an Exercise to have both a primary and a secodary muscle group.

Is it possible to have two icollections in one model and only one in the other?
If someone could help with the "fluent configuration" as well, I would appreciate it!

Here is the code I have got right now.

```
public class Muscle
    {
        public int MuscleID { get; set; }
        public bool IsFront { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    }

    public class Exercise
    {
        public int ExerciseID { get; set; }
        // ExerciseCategory
        public int ExerciseCategoryID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ExerciseCategory ExerciseCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Muscle> MusclesSecondary { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: which way you're going to separately identify those 2 inside the single table (i.e. `Muscles`)? `Muscles` and `MusclesSecondary` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, I'm quite the beginner.
But I want to be able to get like  "var Muscles =  db.Exercises.Where(e => e.ExerciseID == exerciseID.Value).Muscles" and  "var MusclesSecondary =  db.Exercises.Where(e => e.ExerciseID == exerciseID.Value).MusclesSecondary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to map the model you described.
To map your model (2 n-m relationship) you would need a Junction table with a discriminator and you can't do it with EF.

You have several way to change your model to make it work with EF

- You create a model (a class) for the Junction table and insert a discriminator in it. Your model changes (and I think that the new model is less clear)
- Why is there a Muscles and MusclesSecondary? Can it be discriminated with an attribute of Muscle? In this case you can have the attribute in Muscle and remove Exercise.MusclesSecondary Then you have only an n-m relationship that EF handles with a Junction table.
- If you want this model you can add 2 collections to Muscle (for example ExcercisesMuscle and ExercisesMusclesSecondary) and a 3rd not mapped collection where you have the content of ExcercisesMuscle and ExercisesMusclesSecondary toghether. About the ExcercisesMuscle and ExercisesMusclesSecondary they can be observable collections so you can cache the content of Exercises collection in an efficient way.

Comment: I'm not the most experienced developer regarding tables etc. The reasoning behind Muscles and Muscles secondary is that I want an exercis to have, primary musclegroups. Like Benchpress has primary muscles: Pectoralis Major, Anterior deltiod, and secondary: Triceps Brachii.

I dont understand what you mean by discriminated, sry.
Maybe you could give some code example. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Did you mean a property on Mucle, like "bool IsPrimary"? And then just have one Muscle ICollection, and sort the primary and secondary muscles out by LinQ?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. But your poco classes should reflect your world so the question is 'a muscle is always primary or a muscle can be primary and not primary?''. In the second case you should use the third suggested option.

Comment: How would I combine the two collections into Exercises. Is it done in the model? Or in the controller?

Comment: I probably would insert it in the model. If you use only the Exercises collection you could probably not expose other collections to the controller. In this case you won't be able to manage excercises accessing to muscle class (because when you add and remove exercises from muscle you have to do it on ExcercisesMuscle or ExercisesMusclesSecondary)

Comment: I now have a page with categories and exercises associated to that category.
An exercise has multiple Muscles and MusclesSecondary.
I also have a page where all muscles are listed, and if i press one muscle in the list it shows all associated Exercises (As you said, I concated ExercisesMuscle and ExercisesMuscleSecondary).
It now works, thanks!